# How to create two objects that hold a reference to eachother?

Tags: java

```
class A {
    B ob1 = new B();
}

class B {
    A ob2 = new A();
}

class C {
    A a = new A();
   // I am getting a StackOverflowException here 
}
```

I am getting a `StackOverflowException` on the line I commented on. How can I solve this?

Comment: Java is to Javascript as car is to carpet.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? What do you think your code does?

Comment: `A` creates an new `B` which creates a new `A` which creates a new `B` which creates a new `A` which creates a new `B` which creates a new `A` which creates a new `B` which creates a new `A` which creates a new `B` which creates a new `A` which creates a new `B` which creates a new `A` which creates a new `B` which creates a new `A` which creates a new `B` which creates a new `A` which creates a new `B` which creates a new `A` which creates a new `B` which creates a new `A` which creates a new `B` which creates a new `A` which creates a new `B` which creates a new `A` which creates a new...

Answer (score 7):

Problem with your approach is that when you create instance of `A`, this instance have to create instance of `B` which also have to create instance of `A` which creates instance of `B`... and so on until stack will overflow.

---

Probably most intuitive way would to solve this problem with getters/setters like

```
class A{
    private B b;
    public void setB(B b) { this.b = b; }
    public B getB() { return b; }
}

class B{
    private A a;
    public void setA(A a) { this.a = a; }
    public A getA() { return a; }
}

class Demo {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        //let them see each other
        a.setB(b);
        b.setA(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree: construct the objects beforehand and connect them afterwards. No chance of getting any circular references that way.

Comment: This is certainly a valid approach and solves the problem. I would prefer a factory pattern to encapsulate the linking, but that's probably just me being paranoid.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I tried to avoid overcomplicating things but feel free to post answer based on factory pattern. You will get my +1.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the B object to hold a reference to the A object that created it, you want something like this:

```
class A {
    B ob1 = new B(this);
}

class B {
    A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

This will not result in a `StackOverflow` and B will know about A and A will know about B. What you were doing is creating an instance of A which created an instance of B which created an instance of A which created...

Comment: This suggestion leaks `this` in the constructor. This is very bad practice. The only way to resolve this is a static factory method.

Comment: I agree and realize this. In many simple cases, this is not an issue though? However, I'll update my answer later, so thanks.